# How to draw a straight line between two point on canvas with fingure in android

Tags: android

Hi I am beginner in android development. I am developing a paint like application. I have already drawn some points on the canvas. Now I want to draw line between these points through fingure.I dont konw how i can do this. I am not using google maps.

```
 package com.example.point;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DrawView";

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> points1 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
PointF firstpoint=new PointF(100,100);
PointF secondpoint=new PointF(200,200);
Path path=new Path();
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawPoint(100, 100, paint);
        canvas.drawPoint(200, 200, paint);
        canvas.drawPoint(200, 400, paint);
        Point p=new Point();
        Point p1=new Point();
        //p1=points.get(1);
        for(int i=points.size()-2;i<points.size();i++)
        {

            p=points.get(i);
            //if(p1.x==100 && p1.y==100)
        //canvas.drawLine(100, 100, p.x, p.y, paint);
    //  path.moveTo(100, 100);
        //path.lineTo(200, 200);
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }




    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        /*if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
         Point point1 = new Point();          
            point1.x = event.getX();
            point1.y = event.getY();
            points.add(point1);
            invalidate();
            Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point1);


        }*/
        //if(event.getX()==100 && event.getY()==100)
        //{
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
            Point point1 = new Point();          
            point1.x = event.getX();
            point1.y = event.getY();
            points.add(point1);

            invalidate();
            Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point1);
            //}

        }
        //return false;
        return true;



        /*switch (event.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             Point point = new Point();          
             point.x = event.getX();
             point.y = event.getY();
             points.add(point);
             invalidate();
             Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);

             return true;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             Point point1 = new Point();          
             point1.x = event.getX();
             point1.y = event.getY();
             points1.add(point1);
             invalidate();
             Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point1);

             return true;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

             Point point2 = new Point();          
             point2.x = event.getX();
             point2.y = event.getY();
             points2.add(point2);
             invalidate();
             Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point2);

             return true;
         }
     return false;

        //        return true;*/
    }
}

class Point {
    float x, y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

I want to just draw a straight line between these points with fingure. If my fingure move far from that particular point after that i move back my fingure than the line drawn will be erased. i.e. the line only drawn between these particular points.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up here in SO, It is usually best if you'd come and ask here only after you've tried something and didn't succeed. this way you want get comments such as "What have you tried..?" and stuff like that.

Regarding your question. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html is a good place to start. the Android documentation is very helpful.
As you can see you have a [drawLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method. which should do what you asked.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloGoogleMaps extends  MapActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapController mMapController;
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = mapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(18);
      // Two points in Mexico about 1km apart
        GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(19241000,-99121000);
        mMapController.setCenter(point2);
        // Pass the geopoints to the overlay class
        MapOverlay mapOvlay = new MapOverlay(point1, point2);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOvlay);
    }

    public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

      private GeoPoint mGpt1;
      private GeoPoint mGpt2;

      protected MapOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2 ) {
         mGpt1 = gp1;
         mGpt2 = gp2;
      }
      @Override
      public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
         super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
         Paint paint;
         paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
         Point pt1 = new Point();
         Point pt2 = new Point();
         Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
         projection.toPixels(mGpt1, pt1);
         projection.toPixels(mGpt2, pt2);
         canvas.drawLine(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, paint);
         return true;
      }
   }
   @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
   }
}
```

Its Runnnig Code In My Apps..All The Best

Answer (score 0):

Is your canvas sitting inside a View? If so, here is a starting point assuming you are asking about using finger movements to draw lines between points...

Look up the following method for help:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

to detect finger movements. You will need to distinguish between the type of motion action that has just happened, and the motion action "index". Then if the motion is a moving motion (e.g. fingers moving between points), then you can call [drawPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) or [drawLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to draw your lines.